# How to save and retrieve value of radiobutton to SharedPreferences from a multiple choice question

Tags: android, arraylist, radio-button

I'm working on a quiz application.  There are 10 questions, each question has 4 choices (radio button). Technically, user choose a radio button from the first question then press the "next" button to move on to second question. I want to save the user's answers of every question so it can be showed in another activity in a recyclerview, and user can review their answers. I'm confused regarding how to save the value and show it in another activity in a recyclerview, so what should I do? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Here's some code of my activity :

```
private ArrayList<Task> tasks;
//some declaration
    TextView task_question, task_header, timer, count;
    RadioGroup choices_group;
    RadioButton choice_A, choice_B, choice_C, choice_D;
    Button next, previous;

    ProgressDialog loading;
    Token auth = PreferencesConfig.getInstance(this).getToken();
    String token = "Bearer " + auth.getToken();

    int score;
    private int currentTaskId = 0;
    String task_answer;

//onCreate method
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_banksoal_test);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        String judul = intent.getStringExtra("task_title");
        task_header = findViewById(R.id.task_header);
        task_header.setText(judul);

        timer = findViewById(R.id.time);
        task_question = findViewById(R.id.pertanyaan);
        choices_group = findViewById(R.id.rg_question);
        choice_A = findViewById(R.id.option_A);
        choice_B = findViewById(R.id.option_B);
        choice_C = findViewById(R.id.option_C);
        choice_D = findViewById(R.id.option_D);
        count = findViewById(R.id.count);
        next = findViewById(R.id.bNext);
        previous = findViewById(R.id.bPrevious);

    }


//.....


//this is function to retrieve the question
 public void showQuestion(){
        Task task = tasks.get(currentTaskId);
        task_question.setText(task.getSoal());
        choice_A.setText(task.getOption_A());
        choice_B.setText(task.getOption_B());
        choice_C.setText(task.getOption_C());
        choice_D.setText(task.getOption_D());
        task_answer = task.getJawaban();
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedId = choices_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton selectedRB = findViewById(selectedId);
                if (selectedRB.getText().toString().equals(task_answer)){
                   score+=10;
                }

                if (currentTaskId < tasks.size() - 1){
                    currentTaskId++;
                    showQuestion();
                    selectedRB.setChecked(false);
                    choices_group.clearCheck();

                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TaskActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score", score);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SharedPreferences you can do this:

```
int answer_number = 4;
String answer = "the answer of the user";

//Your id is the identifier and location of your SharedPreferences because you can have
//multiple instances of SharedPrefernces.
String id = "quiz-application";

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(id, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//The editor
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(String.valueOf(answer_number), answer);
editor.apply();
```

By doing this you can save in your "quiz_application".sharedpreferences file your answers and later access them by doing this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(id, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String answer = sharedRef.getString("1", "no answer found");
//The 1 being the answer number while the second parameter being a fail-safe, 
//if there isn't anything there it would return "no answer found".
```

Bear in mind you still need the id and the answer number to get the information back. The answer number, in this case, is simple, it can only take these values: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}. What you need to take care of is the id.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try. I'll inform you later if there are some error

Comment: Great. If there is some error specify it correctly.

Comment: I already did your instruction, I still confuse how and where to call the sharedpref? in adapter on in another activity? if u remember I use a recyclerview.

Comment: The first option use it to save the radio button selections and put it the button where you go to the next activity. The second option put it in the activity where you want to show the selections.